# comparing variables for validate addMethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, validation, contains

Ive been struggling with this all day, been close a couple times but nothing seems to work exactly.

I have a text input `<input type="text" name="USA_sub" id="USA_sub" />` and after that an input `<input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" />` I need to make sure (create a validation rule) that states "#FirstName" 's value  must be contained in "#USA_sub" 's value.

I keep getting the error "$(sig).contains is not a function" with this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("FNESig", function (value, element) {
    var firstname = $("#FirstName").val();
    var sig = $("#USA_sub").val();

    if ($(sig).contains(firstname)) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
}, "Your First Name must be in your Electronic Signature.");
```

thx
Kane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this (`$().contains()` isn't a method...and you have a string, not a selector for a jQuery object, no need to wrap anything):

```
if ($(sig).contains(firstname)) {
    return true;
    } else return false;
```

You can just use [`string.indexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp), like this:

```
return sig.indexOf(firstname) != -1; //-1 would mean it wasn't found
```

---

As a side note, since you're returning the same result as the condition, just return it, in other words this:

```
if(someCondition) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Can just be:

```
return someCondition;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (sig.indexOf(firstname) >= 0) {
    return true;
} else return false;
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It's correct, he has `>= 0`, not just `> 0`. +1

Answer (score 1):

[`contains`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) method in jQuery can only be applied to DOM elements. You may want to use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) javascript method instead. It will search for an occurrence of the specified value in a string

```
$.validator.addMethod("FNESig", function (value, element) {
    var firstname = $("#FirstName").val();
    var sig = $("#USA_sub").val();

    // means: does sig contains firstname?
    return (sig.indexOf(firstname) !== -1);

}, "Your First Name must be in your Electronic Signature.");
```